# How to make best use of multithreading with monte carlo simulations?

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, performance, parallel-processing

I am writing a code to benchmark simulation algorithms using the basics of Monte carlo simulations - so I am generating a random system (just an integer) and running the simulation algorithms on the randomly generated system. I need to do this many many times and although the algorithms are relatively conceptually simple they take a few seconds to run because they contain many loops.

```
for i=1:number of algorithms
    for i=1:number of repeats
        if algo = 1
            //run the first algorithm [for loops]
        if algo = 2
            //run the second algorithm [while]
        if algo = 3
            //run the third algorithm [while]
```

where each algorithm works differently. The first algorithm can be further broken down into for loops where it is run many times and the highest score is selected so I imagine even the algorithm could be multithreaded. The other two would be much more complex to make multithreaded.

My question is how to split the program into different threads. There appears to be many different ways I could approach this and I am very new to multithreading so I have no idea what would be best.

**Option 1**: Split the threads immediately and run different algorithms on each thread.

**Option 2**: Split the threads with the second for loop, so the number of repeats are split up over the different threads.

**Option 3**: Try to break down the algorithm steps into smaller chunks which can be parallelized

Comment: What you call repeats are repetitions for statistics or actually different set of parameters?

Comment: Of course the trivial parallelization is to do Option 1 or Option 1 with the two for loops inverted that for me looks more natural :P. Nevertheless, that trivial parallelization is basically the same as taking out the loop from your C code and launch the executable from a script as many times as cores you have. And the advantage in this case is that is way more flexible and you can also put it trivially in a cluster.

Comment: But of course there are specifics of your problem. If one computation time of the different algorithms differ, you won't want to put each algorithm in a thread, because one thread will be done faster and you will be wasting computation power/time. So, option 2 wouldn't be a good idea if that's the case. And option 1 sounds better. As for option 3: well, here you will probably need to work much much more about it, first estimating whether you would get any advantage compared with option 1.

Comment: @myradio the repeats begin with a different random seed but always the same paramaters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in how long would it take to each repetition and each algorithm to be executed. Assuming that each repetition takes the same as the others (for each particular algorithm), most likely the best for these kind of cases is to trivially split the outer for in different threads (switching the two for loops to have repetitions that take the same time).

Running each algorithm in a different thread instead would have no advantage, since the algorithms are not going to take exactly the same time and you will end up wasting computational power.

Option 3 sounds very unlikely for a case like this. Besides the fact that you will have to think and make a significantly more complex program, I doubt you can gain something from paralellizing the different parts of the algorithm and I think is more likely that the code will be slower due to the different threads having to wait each other.

As a side note, as I said in the comments, for this very simple cases of parallelization I would recommend you to consider splitting the runs outside the C code but in a shell script. Each job you launch will be run in a different core and you will gain a lot of flexibility. You will also be able to run in in a cluster with almost no changes if any.

Comment: How would I run the same script multiple times using a shell script?

Comment: If you have your algorithms in C then you would run the executable binary from a shell script. You can run `./binary.exe &` in a for loop in a script and it won't wait to it to finish (due to the `&`). 
It does not need to be a binary executable (I said that because you used the c tag) you can do the same replacing ./binary.exe with any executable (and that includes matlab since that seems to be your code) in a shell. But I guess this is going a bit outside the scope of the question.

Comment: so the `&` tells the script to run it in parallel? will it automatically run on different threads? I am writing in C, the code I provided was just pseudo code.

Comment: No. The `&` just let you execute a command in a script and send it to background instead of waiting for it to finish. If you put `./binary.exe` in a loop in a script, each iteration of the script will wait for the program to finish, while putting the `&` allows you to run it in the background letting the script to go to the next iteration. And yes, if you run the same (single core) executable several times the OS will attempt to distribute it in the different cores. You can test that by launching your executable several times and monitor the system which in unix you would do with `top`.

Comment: You can ask a new question about parallelizing code using a script. Also, feel free to accept the answer if you think it answers to your question ^^